# Can you Install Ubuntu From a USB on a Windows 8.1 Computer

Tags: boot, windows, menu

I'm Having some problems installing Ubuntu on my Samsung Windows 8.1 computer. When I go into my BIOS setup menu, it doesn't have an option to boot from my USB.

I am trying to download everything and install it again.  Just thought I could get some help here.

Comment: Why you are even downloading again and installing what! If your MB doesn't support boot from USB "which I highly doubt if your computer support Windows 8.1" then you can easily burn the **.iso** file to a DVD and boot from it!

Comment: How did you create your USB? Go over to pendrivelinux.net and use their free software. It works like a charm. If your Samsung doesn't boot from USB, that probably means that it doesn't see any bootable USB devices on your system or that SECURE BOOT is enabled. Press F10 to get the boot menu at start without having to mess with your default BIOS settings. (check http://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd as well)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if I am right or not but, I found my USB from HDDD. Just go to Boot>First priority> HDDD. After that find HDDD at the bottom of the thing. Open that and follow the instructions to make your USB on top of the list and then restart. Have Fun! I just got this today but, it seems kinda slow.

Edit: You also need to make your iso file into a bootloader. Do this before you actually try to install it in the BIOS.